# Youtube search query wtih Ruby

Tags: ruby, youtube

How can I fetch the first video's url from a youtube search query?

I found [this](https://github.com/grosser/youtube_search) gem. It does exactly what I'm looking for, but uses outdated code since youtube switched to API v3, and there don't seem to be any other up to date gems out there like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use other up-to-date Youtube gems like [yt](https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt). Alternatively, you can just query YouTube's REST API using any http library. I've just skimmed through the api docs, and it seems to be straightforward. It returns JSON object which you can easily parse and get the first video details.